# Twitter Login in fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, twitter-login

I tried the same code in Activity and it worked but the same code in fragment doesn't work.

SignUpFragment.java:

```
package com.conversionbug.alltee;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthToken;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

import static com.conversionbug.alltee.Constants.ROOT_LOGIN;
import static com.conversionbug.alltee.Constants.ROOT_TOKEN;
import static com.conversionbug.alltee.Constants.SOCIAL_REGISTER;

import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;

public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    TextView loginTV;
    Button nextActivity;
    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    LinearLayout linear_main;

    String googleName;
    String googleEmail;
    String googleUserAccessToken;
    String googleUserSocialId;

    String facebookEmail;
    String facebookId;
    String facebookName;
    String facebookToken;

    ImageButton facebook_icon1;
    LoginButton facebook_sign_in_button1;
    ImageButton google_plus_icon1;
    SignInButton googleSignIn1;

    ImageButton twitter_icon;

    TwitterLoginButton twitter1;

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient1;
    private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions;

    TwitterSession session;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        Twitter.initialize(getActivity()); //Twitter is initialized

        loginTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.loginTV);
        nextActivity = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);
        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        linear_main = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearMain1);
        facebook_icon1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon1);
        facebook_sign_in_button1 = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_sign_in_button1);

        facebook_sign_in_button1.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        twitter1 = (TwitterLoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.twitter1);
        twitter_icon = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);

        google_plus_icon1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.google_plus_icon1);
        googleSignIn1 = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.googleSignIn1);
        facebook_sign_in_button1.setFragment(this);

        signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();
        googleApiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                //.enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, 1, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions)
                .build();

        try {
            session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }


        facebook_icon1.setOnClickListener(this);
        google_plus_icon1.setOnClickListener(this);
        twitter_icon.setOnClickListener(this);



        facebook_sign_in_button1.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
                                FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

                                facebookToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();


                                try {
                                    facebookEmail = object.getString("email");
                                    facebookId = object.getString("id");
                                    facebookName = object.getString("name");


                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email: " + facebookEmail + " Id: " + facebookId + " Name: " + facebookName + " Access Token: " + facebookToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                FacebookRegisterTask facebookRegisterTask = new FacebookRegisterTask();
                                facebookRegisterTask.execute(SOCIAL_REGISTER);
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "email,id,name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        loginTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view1) {
                Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        nextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RegisterTask registerTask = new RegisterTask();
                registerTask.execute(ROOT_LOGIN);

                String nameValidation = name.getText().toString().trim();
                String emailValidation = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String passwordValidation = password.getText().toString().trim();
                String namePattern = "[A-Za-z. ]+";
                String emailPattern = "[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
                if (nameValidation.matches(namePattern) && name.length() <= 255 && emailValidation.matches(emailPattern) && passwordValidation.length() >= 6) {

                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(linear_main, "Wrong Username or Password !!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    textView.setTextSize(16f);
                    sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.red));
                    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                        textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                    else
                        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        });

        twitter1.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;

                session = result.data;
                String userName = session.getUserName().toString();
                long userId = session.getId();

                if(userName.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data isn't fetched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful with token: " + token + "\n secret: " + secret + "\n User Name: " + userName + "\n Id: " + userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                /*getUserData();*/
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"inside onActivityResult",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleResult(result);
        }
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.linearMain1);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /*void getUserData() {
        TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
        authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void success(Result<String> result1) {

                String s1 = result1.data.toString().toLowerCase();
                if(s1.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No EmailId",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Email: "+s1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
    }
*/

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.facebook_icon1:
                facebook_sign_in_button1.performClick();
                break;

            case R.id.google_plus_icon1:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.twitter_icon:
                twitter1.performClick();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed G+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            googleName = account.getDisplayName();
            googleEmail = account.getEmail();
            googleUserAccessToken = account.getIdToken();
            googleUserSocialId = account.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name: " + googleName + " Email: " + googleEmail + " UserAccessToken: " + googleUserAccessToken + " UserSocialId " + googleUserSocialId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            GoogleRegisterTask googleRegisterTask = new GoogleRegisterTask();
            googleRegisterTask.execute(SOCIAL_REGISTER);
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (googleApiClient1 != null)
            googleApiClient1.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (googleApiClient1 != null && googleApiClient1.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient1.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("name", name.getText().toString())
                        .add("email", email.getText().toString())
                        .add("password", password.getText().toString())
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                AuthTask authTask = new AuthTask();
                authTask.execute(ROOT_TOKEN);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (s.toString().equals("{\"error\":\"Email id already taken\"}")) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email-id already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public class AuthTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode1;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params1) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("client_id", "2")
                        .add("client_secret", "oreOeeeN7ZYpCGNFMmW2W1OowPQVaJ92jadcl8B2")
                        .add("grant_type", "password")
                        .add("scope", "*")
                        .add("username", email.getText().toString())
                        .add("password", password.getText().toString())
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params1[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode1 = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();

                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public class GoogleRegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("name", googleName)
                        .add("email", googleEmail)
                        .add("access_token", googleUserAccessToken)
                        .add("social_id", googleUserSocialId)
                        .add("social", "google_id")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                GoogleAuthTask googleAuthTask = new GoogleAuthTask();
                googleAuthTask.execute(ROOT_TOKEN);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    public class GoogleAuthTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode1;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params1) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("grant_type", "social")
                        .add("client_id", "2")
                        .add("client_secret", "oreOeeeN7ZYpCGNFMmW2W1OowPQVaJ92jadcl8B2")
                        .add("access_token", googleUserAccessToken)
                        .add("network", "google_id")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params1[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode1 = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();

                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public class FacebookRegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("name", facebookName)
                        .add("email", facebookEmail)
                        .add("access_token", facebookToken)
                        .add("social_id", facebookId)
                        .add("social", "facebook_id")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            FacebookAuthTask facebookAuthTask = new FacebookAuthTask();
            facebookAuthTask.execute(ROOT_TOKEN);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BottomNavigationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + responseCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public class FacebookAuthTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int responseCode1;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params1) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody postData = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("grant_type", "social")
                        .add("client_id", "2")
                        .add("client_secret", "oreOeeeN7ZYpCGNFMmW2W1OowPQVaJ92jadcl8B2")
                        .add("access_token", facebookToken)
                        .add("network", "facebook_id")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(params1[0])
                        .post(postData)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                responseCode1 = response.code();
                String result = response.body().string();

                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}  }
    }
}
```

fragment_sign_up.xml:`

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
                android:id="@+id/twitter1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon" />
            </FrameLayout>`
```

After clicking on the button, it is redirecting to the twitter login page and after clicking on "connect" button, it simply returns to the fragment and doesn't show the Toast message. When I Click the button for the second time, it shows toast from failure method.

Comment: Oh Fragment problem is arise

Comment: now fabric doesn't give option for twitter login....I tried that.

Comment: twitter sold fabric to google this year and google has removed the option of twitter login it seems.

Comment: Thank you for your information

Comment: Let me know if you find something.

Comment: Are u sure Activity result is working in fragment

Comment: Attach the full fragment code checking the views are assign correct or not

Comment: noActivityResult() is not getting called.

Comment: Ya i Know this OnActivity result is working in activity if u attach full code then try to fix the problem

Comment: Should I post the whole code?

Comment: i think post the  fragment code is enough. k post the whole code

Comment: check the fragment code now

Comment: Fragment concept is wrong

Comment: U useing the frame layourt but declare all variable of outside fragment

Comment: Didn't get it..

Comment: Are you saying that all variables are declared outside the fragment?

Comment: Activity fie is need

Comment: activity fie is need????...What do you really want to ask?

Comment: Bcoz where the frame layout is declare

Comment: linear_main = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearMain1);

Comment: this is the layout.

Comment: Sry to say that this is totally wron for creating fragment.

Comment: What is wrong? Be specific.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Few hours later  i send the fragment structure bcoz i'm in company

Comment: Dude everything works fine except twitter login code.

Comment: Dude, R u sure every think is works fine

Comment: yes man. In twitter login the onStartActivity() isn't getting called, that's the only issue.

Comment: Dude I think All the codes are executing like as activity

Comment: If that was the reason, Then twitter login also would have worked.

Comment: twiiter u access like as fragment

Comment: Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.linearMain1);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

Comment: Written same in the documentation.  [link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter)

Comment: And also i Know Facebook also work in fragment

Comment: I think the error arise in this line      .....  
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.linearMain1);      .... k See u Later

Comment: that is not even getting called

Answer (score 0):

just add in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        yourcurrentfragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```